# Best practices creating data models with same properties

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

New to MVC and looking for best practice when multiple models have the same properties. For example I have several models that have the address fields (address, city, state and zipcode). Let's say I have a customer model and supplier model with these fields. What is the best way to create the model? First example I started with has:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string MainPhone { get; set; }
    public string fax { get; set; }
    public string ContactPhone { get; set; }
}

public class Supplier
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string Supplier { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string MainPhone { get; set; }
    public string fax { get; set; }
    public string ContactPhone { get; set; }
}
```

or alternately:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public Address CustomerAddress { get; set; }
    public Phone MainPhone { get; set; }
    public Phone fax { get; set; }
    public Phone ContactPhone { get; set; }
}

public class Supplier
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string Supplier { get; set; }
    public Address SupplierAddress { get; set; }
    public Phone MainPhone { get; set; }
    public Phone fax { get; set; }
    public Phone ContactPhone { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
}

public class Phone
{
    public int AreaCode { get; set; }
    public int NPA { get; set; }
    public int Station { get; set; }
}
```

Any suggestions on what is considered best practice is very much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that this is any different for MVC than for anything else, but IMO, the second is far better.  When you decide to add a work address and home address, just like you already have a few phone numbers, you won't have to come up with even more contrived names to differentiate.  All the standard reasons for reusable code would still apply.